# Website displays in chrome perfectly, but not in mozilla or IE

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

here are the code snippets for the html and css. It works finds in Google chrome, but when I try to display it in mozilla or IE, it shows something completely different. I cannot attach images as I do not have the required reputation. I really appreciate the help. Thank you!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="ak.png">
  <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="Nav">
            <nav>
                <ul class="navigation fade-in2">
                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#shop">Shop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="logo"><a href="#home"><img class="ak fade-in2" src="ak.png"></a></div>

    <div class="background"><img class="beauty" src="beauty.jpg"></div>
    <div class="header">
        <h1 class="headerName fade-in">DESIGN | DEVELOP | BRAND</h1>
        <h4 class="service fade-in3"><a href="#portfolio">VIEW PORTFOLIO</a></h4>
        <h4 class="service fade-in3"><a href="#services">VIEW SERVICES</a></h4>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="mainbody"><p>safsdaf</p></div>-->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: verdana;

}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #222222;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 47px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
}


.ak{
    width: 90px;
    height: 55px;
    z-index: 101;
    position: fixed;
    background: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
}


.Nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px;
}

.Nav a:link{
    color: #A7A7A7;

}

.Nav a:visited{
    color: #A7A7A7;

}

.Nav a:hover{

    color: #DBDBDB;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

.header {

    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.25);
    width: 100%;
    height: 626px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}


.background {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 8;



}

.beauty {
    width: 100%;
    height: 626px;

}


.headerName {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #D3D3D3;
    padding: 180px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    margin: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}



.fade-in {
    opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animation ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
    -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;

    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.3s;
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.fade-in2 {
    opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animation ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
    -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;

    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.6s;
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.fade-in3 {
    opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animation ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
    -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;

    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.9s;
    animation-delay: 0.9s;
}

.service{
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 190px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: #D3D3D3;
    border: 2px #A7A7A7 solid;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    letter-spacing: 2px;



}



.service a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
}

.service a:link{
    color: #D3D3D3;

}

.service a:visited{
    color: #D3D3D3;

}

.service a:hover{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
    transition: background-color .15s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .15s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: background-color .15s ease-in;
    -o-transition: background-color .15s ease-in;
}
```

UPDATE 1: I updated both browsers and it seems the css3 animations work perfectly fine on both browsers. What seems to be the problem is the positioning of the pages

UPDATE 2: Here are the links to the different browser screen shots

Chrome: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jlpa4vu51kdnews/Chrome.JPG

InternetExplorer: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zbchs3su9ahxr0n/IE.JPG

Mozilla Firefox: dropbox(.)com/s/fyalnhsha9ktadz/Mozilla.JPG (I can't post the third link because I don't have enough reputation)

--- Notice in chrome the logo in the top left looks smooth while the other two not so much. I believe the pictures are self explanatory.

Comment: Post links to your screenshots here and somebody will embed them in your question

Comment: who uses anything other than chrome anyways?

Comment: @NoahHerron Firefox is still *very* popular, for lots of reasons

Comment: @NoahHerron nobody but 60% of total users :(

Comment: @NoahHerron In China, there are a lot of people who don't know much about computer are still using IE6.:(

Comment: which version of mozilla or IE your using.
html5 document only support IE 9 onwards .

Comment: @3rror404 I have done just that. Thank You!

Comment: @TonyChen Im said to hear that :(. I just want you guys to know. I just downloaded Firefox. Chrome doesn't support everything...obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chendatony31/ap50mnyb/1/). Is this what you want?

Just changing first line of your css file.

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
```

Comment: Hmm sorry that seems to be a mistake on my part when posting the question, my code was like that in the beginning. Thanks though and the problem isn't the animation, its the position of different code blocks

Answer (score 0):

## Problem with IE8 and Earlier version

IE8 and earlier does not know how to render CSS on elements that it doesn't recognize. You cannot style new HTML5 elements like **header, nav , section**

but **HTML 5 shiv** javascript file is used to enable styling of HTML5 elements in versions of Internet Explorer prior to version 9.

you can download it from http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

To enable the HTML5 Shiv (after downloading), insert the following code into the  element:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Well I was using the later version of IE so that wasn't the case

Comment: @AtharulKhan i just want to say that if you want HTML5 tags working in older version of IE. You can use above solution.